# Spring CSRF + AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I Already tried many of the aswers about this topic, no one works for me.

I Have a basic CRUD with Spring MVC 4.1.7, Spring Security 3.2.3 working on MySQL + Tomcat7.

The problem is, when i try to POST form with AngularJS, I keep being blocked by error 403 ( access denied ).

I figured out that I need to send my CSRF_TOKEN with the POST request, but I can't figure out HOW!

I Tried so many diferent ways and no one works.

My Files

Controller.js

```
$scope.novo = function novo() {
  if($scope.id){
   alert("Update - " + $scope.id);
  }
  else{
      var Obj = {
              descricao : 'Test',
              saldo_inicial : 0.00,
              saldo : 33.45,
              aberto : false,
              usuario_id : null,
              ativo : true
      };
      $http.post(urlBase + 'caixas/adicionar', Obj).success(function(data) {
          $scope.caixas = data;    
      }).error(function(data) {alert(data)});
  }
 };
```

Spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/seguro**"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/seguro/financeiro**"
        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_FINANCEIRO','ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/negado" />
    <form-login login-page="/home/" default-target-url="/seguro/"
        authentication-failure-url="/home?error" username-parameter="inputEmail"
        password-parameter="inputPassword" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/home?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT login, senha, ativo
               FROM usuarios 
              WHERE login = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.login, r.role
               FROM usuarios_roles r, usuarios u
              WHERE u.id = r.usuario_id
                AND u.login = ?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Barattie ~ Soluções Integradas</display-name>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-database.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-hibernate.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/erro</location>
</error-page>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to add to rename at client side the xsrf, but I keep getting access denied.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = '_csrf';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-Token';
});
```

** UPDATE 2 **

I tried to implement a filter like this.

```
package sys.barattie.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class CsrfFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    if (csrf != null) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", csrf.getToken());
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

And changed my spring security to it.

```
     <csrf token-repository-ref="csrfTokenRepository" />
<beans:bean id="csrfTokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
    <beans:property name="headerName" value="X-XSRF-TOKEN" />
</beans:bean>
```

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>csrfFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>sys.barattie.util.CsrfFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

But it is like that the server doesn't run the filter, I've added a System.out.println to it, but can't see the messages in the debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some tests and end up with this.

In my login controller, if my user authentication is successful, I create a token with the name of the AngularJS Token, just like this.

```
CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
if (csrf != null) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", csrf.getToken());
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

After that, I can manage my $http.post successfully.

I don't know if this is the best way, but is the way that worked for me!

Thanks for the help @Joao Evangelista

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the integration, Angular always look for a cookie name XSRF-TOKEN and Spring sends a CSRF_TOKEN, you need to provide a filter to change this. Something like this:

```
private static Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName())
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN")
                    String token = csrf.getToken()
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token)
                        cookie.setPath("/")
                        response.addCookie(cookie)
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
            }
        }
    }

    static CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository()
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN")
        return repository
    }
```

*NOTICE* The only example I have is this, is written in Groovy, but is just missing some `;`

Then you need to add the filter and the repository to `<csrf/>` properties, you can explicity set a class implementing a Filter as `<bean>`, using `@Component` or declaring this methods as `@Bean` on a configuration class

Otherwise you can change the `$http` configuration on Angular, according to docs setting this settings to match Spring token cookie name and header name

```
xsrfHeaderName – {string} – Name of HTTP header to populate with the XSRF token.
xsrfCookieName – {string} – Name of cookie containing the XSRF token.
```

More info about this you can check the docs on [Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) section

Comment: I tried to implement the $http config at client side, setting
`var app = angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($httpProvider) {
 $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
 $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
});`

But I keep getting Access denied...I will try at server side

Comment: the default header name is `X-CSRF-TOKEN`

Comment: Changed the cookieName to _csrf, and the header to X-CSRF-TOKEN, nothing...

Also I tried to implement the server side solution and I cant made it, the IDE keeps trying to replace the "static Filter" with "OncePerRequestFilter"

Comment: as I remember `_csrf` is not the cookie name, make a simple request using Chrome, access the cookie pages, and check it there, also the OncePerRequestFilter implements Filter try to remove the static modifier, or ignore your IDE

Comment: Did it, the token name is "JSESSIONID", and it is set to HttpOnly

Comment: Changed the name of the token to JSESSIONID, still doesn't work :(

About CsrfFilter...Type mismatch: cannot convert from new OncePerRequestFilter(){} to Filter

Comment: Updated the Question, about the server side filter.

Comment: Could you please provide CsrfToken class? Thanks, Anita

Comment: @user4567570 `CsrfToken` is present on the spring-securty sources, the full name is `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken`, just import it.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing this problem also, and this is the solution that is working for me (from the Spring documentation), notice that im not using $http. Instead im using $resource.
'
You can ask Spring to save a cookie with Angular's defaults:

```
<csrf token-repository-ref="tokenRepository"/>
```

...
     `</http>`

```
<b:bean id="tokenRepository"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository"
    p:cookieHttpOnly="false"/>
```

Please notice that if you use $http, there is a field in the config object called **xsrfCookieName**, where you can set explicitly the name of the cookie. But this option i havent tried it, so i dont know how useful it is.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Class that  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
..
```

And then in your AngularJS you can use any module for csrf, etc.: [spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spring-security-csrf-token-interceptor)