# How do I send CSRF tokens from AngularJS front end to Spring REST service backend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-security

**How do I set up CSRF protection between an AngularJS front end and a Spring Boot REST backend?**  Let's take the `http.post("/send-pin", JSONobject)...` call from the code below as an example.

I am getting the following error in the server logs when I try to call a Spring Boot REST service at the `/send-pin` url pattern from an AngularJS front end method using `http.post("/send-pin", JSONobject)...`:

```
Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9000/send-pin
```

I read [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731699/spring-rest-service-invalid-csrf-token-when-i-attempt-to-login), which states that the csrf token needs to be set in the AngularJS code that makes the request, but the code in the link uses the syntax `$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);});`, which does not directly paste into my code below.  Also, the clode in the link takes data from a form, while my code takes data from an AngularJS controller.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the backend REST service will successfully process the request made by the AngularJS app to the REST service running at the `localhost:9000/send-pin` url?**

Here is the method in AngularJS:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    auth.authenticate1($scope.credentials, function(authenticated1) {
        if (authenticated1) {//authenticated1 returns true
            var resultmessage = { "name": $scope.credentials.username };
            $http.post('/send-pin', resultmessage).then(function(response) {//this call triggers the Invalid CSRF token error shown above
                $scope.processStep = response.data.content;
                auth.usrname = response.data.name;
            });
            $scope.error = false;
        } else {
            $scope.error = true;
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the UiApplication.java class that sets the SpringSecurity configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "demo", considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class UiApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // Match everything without a suffix (so not a static resource)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
        return "forward:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Principal user(HttpSession session, Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Users users;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(users);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/check-pin").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/someotherrurl") 
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

        private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                    if (csrf != null) {
                        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                        String token = csrf.getToken();
                        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                            cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
                        }
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            };
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }   
}
```

Here is the error log from the Linux terminal which prints out while the REST service is running:

```
2016-01-15 13:15:27.704 DEBUG 7031 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-15 13:15:27.704 DEBUG 7031 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] tRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper : Skip invoking on
2016-01-15 13:15:27.704 DEBUG 7031 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-01-15 13:15:27.704 DEBUG 7031 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/css/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/js/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/images/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/error'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/autoconfig'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/autoconfig/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/autoconfig.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/autoconfig/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/autoconfig/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/metrics'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/metrics/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/metrics.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/metrics/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.713 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/trace'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/trace/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/trace.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/trace/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/trace/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/env'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/env/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/env.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/env/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/env/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/health']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/health'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/health/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/health/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/mappings'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/mappings/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/mappings.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/mappings/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/mappings/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/dump'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/dump/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/dump.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/dump/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/dump/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/error'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.714 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/error/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.715 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/error/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.715 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.716 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/beans'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.716 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.716 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/beans/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/beans.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/beans/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/beans/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/info']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/info'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/info/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/info/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/configprops'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops/**']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/configprops/**'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops.*']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/configprops.*'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/configprops/']
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/send-pin'; against '/configprops/'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /send-pin at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /send-pin at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@d8393cb4: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@d8393cb4: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@63d9948c: Username: another@shirt.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffdaa08: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 61483B5DDC3336EC44BF528C97749AA9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /send-pin at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.717 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@4f81666
2016-01-15 13:15:27.723 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /send-pin at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-01-15 13:15:27.724 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9000/send-pin
2016-01-15 13:15:27.725 DEBUG 7031 --- [io-9000-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: I am the OP, and this answer is what actually resolved the problem.**

The solution to this required adding the following line to the `SecurityConfiguration` class:

```
.antMatchers("/send-pin").permitAll()
```

This change caused SecurityConfiguration.configure(...) method to now look like:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/send-pin").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/check-pin").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/login", "/someotherrurl") 
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
```

Notice the one line change from the OP version.  This is a very simple answer.  Almost ashamed to post it because it is so obvious, but I am posting it to help others who face a similar problem in the future.

I found this after trying @charlieti's suggestion to examine the Network tab of the Firefox debug tools, which showed that the following two cookies were sent with the request: `JSESSIONID:"99192501E7CEA0EDEF853BD666AF3C35"` and `XSRF-TOKEN:"b50afb87-e15c-4bef-93ca-7c2fdf145fd8"`, even though the server log for the same request still boiled down to `Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9000/send-pin` .  This caused me to examine why the sent token was being rejected, and a few minutes later I noticed the missing `antmatchers(...)` for the url pattern, leading to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajaxSend` will only work for jQuery `$.ajax` and not for other ajax calls made by another library or framework such as angular.

From [angular $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> XSRF is a technique by which an unauthorized site can gain your user's private data. Angular provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN).

So make sure you set appropriate cookie and angular will take care of the header internally

Comment: sorry I don't know anything about spring but it should be easy enough to look up csrf cookie handling

Comment: shouldn't be hard to look up in manual. Also simple to see what cookies are set on any page using browser dev tools

Comment: I found this in 15 seconds using google `spring csrf cookie`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389120/spring-csrf-angularjs

Comment: use browser dev tools network to inspect actual request. Can see exactly what is sent including cookies. Also , is this cross domain? different port for example? If so would need to add `withCredentials` to request

Comment: also check that server config won't need a new token each request

Comment: I found the Spring solution to this question, and posted it as a separate answer because it is different from this, and it is what actually resolved the problem.  +1 for the time you invested trying to help me. Thank you again.